# How do I make stairs?

Tags: terraria

How do I make stairs in Terraria? It's getting really annoying that NPC's can't go up platforms.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are looking for something that has the functionality like the platforms, where you can optionally go through them or up them, then that is not possible to make in a staircase.

With the changes in 1.2 though, everything should be able to walk up and down a 1 to 1 elevation change. So you can just make a tile of blocks that anyone can walk up and down. You can even use the hammer to make it look like a slope if you wanted, but this is optional and up to your taste in how you want it to appear.

Edit: interesting bit of new information from playing. You can place down Ingots of different metals and these act as a background as well as a foreground. How the AI will deal with them is a bit odd so far and I have not been able to rigorously test this, but these give you a set of stairs you can jump and land on or just simply walk past them. This may be a solution to your problem. I will update with more exact information as I find it, but it is a tentative third option.

Comment: Do you mean build a slope of blocks that npc's could walk up?

Comment: Basically yes. AI are able to go up and down and make jumps of a certain height. But if you want a true staircase its just make one out of blocks unfortunately.

Comment: is there anyway to do it in xbox360 edition?

Answer (score 18):

As of version 1.2.3, if you place a [Platform](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Platform) of any type, and hit it with a hammer (essentially making it a *sloped* platform), the platform will transform itself into a staircase. Here's the relevant line from the changelog for 1.2.3:

> You can now turn platforms into stairs using the hammer.

[Here's a video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MdEqLGPZPlA) from YouTube demonstrating how this works.

Comment: Can NPCs use these stairs?

Comment: Yes, I believe they can.

Answer (score 2):

There is now a faster way to build stairs without the hammer:

On the PC version, you can select a platform and hold down the "Ctrl" key. This will highlight a single block were the platform can be placed. If you place them in a diagonal instead of horizontal, it will automatically become stairs.

Not sure how it is done in xbox or other versions.